# regex to match pattern while excluding other pattern in the text

Tags: regex, matching

i have one file which includes texts  like

```
lets say my input text is || text || || text || || text || || 1 || || 2 ||
```

i want to match only || from the text at the same time i want to exclude occurrences of numbers with digits with this pattern  || 0-9 ||

so i made one regex

(\||) : this will match || in the text but my problem is i am also getting ||0-9|| which is understandable so i add one more filter in regex

`(\||) ([0-9+])` : this will match all texts like   `text|| 1 || text|| 3 ||`

finally , i want to ignore this pattern which is matched by

```
(\||) ([0-9+])
```

and get the results by only `(\||)` , so the output

||\n text ||\n ||\n text ||\n ||\n text ||\n || 1 || || 2 ||

so how can i ignore/discard matched pattern from regex

option1 : (?:expression )(its not working )

(\||) (\|| [0-9+]....// i dont want to affect this pattern while matching first group )

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Do you want to *remove* the 0-9 terms by match-and-replace, or do you want *find* all non 0-9 terms, or do you want a regex that matches the entire input only if it doesn't contain number-only terms?

Comment: lets say my input text is || text || || text || || text || || 1 || || 2 || || 3 || so the output will be  ||\n text ||\n ||\n text ||\n ||\n| text ||\n || 1 || || 2 || || 3 ||

Comment: @Bohemian : you guess it correctly , regex should  match the input if it  doesn't contain number-only terms

Comment: @user3141544 provide the expected output in your question.. Are you trying to split the input?

Comment: Which language you're running?

Comment: @Avinash Raj  : i am executing regex in excel file.. yup splitting but not from everywhere . i would split  where i found || and i will not split if i found any digits after || . for example, it would not  in this case || 1 || ,|| 2 ||

Answer (score 0):

> finally , i want to ignore this pattern which is matched by
>
> `(\||) ([0-9+])`

```
\|\|\s*\d+\s*(*SKIP)(*F)|\|\|
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aQ7yS5/2)

I assumed that you're running php.

OR

```
\|\|(?!\s*\d+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aQ7yS5/3)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming valid terms may contain digits too (and letters), you need a regex that matches the general pattern but *excludes* there being any digit-only terms.

Use a negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*\|\| \d+ \|\|)(\|\| \w+ \|\| ?)+$
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/C5KHNnM1E1)